# Deserializing null value in JSON

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I need some help in JSON desereialization of null value, there is an error in the output window but I don't know what is the cause, the error is:

```
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
```

The JSON looks like this:

> [{"TID":"1","taskdescript":"Tank","taskstatus":"1","username":"administrator","prjdescript":"XXX","dateuseraccept":**null**,"estimatedduration":"0","actualduration":"0"}]

The portion of the code that is handling the deserialize looks like this:

```
    .....
    Dim responsebody = (New Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(responsebytes)
    'Dim settings = New JsonSerializerSettings()
    'settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include
    'settings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
    'settings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
    Console.WriteLine(responsebody)
    Dim datacollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of jsonPrjData())(responsebody)

    For Each oneVar As jsonPrjData In datacollection
        ' Avoid Nothing vars.
        MsgBox(oneVar.TID.ToString)
        If oneVar IsNot Nothing Then
            datagrid.Rows.Add(oneVar.TID, oneVar.taskDescript, oneVar.taskStatus, oneVar.prjDescript, oneVar.username, oneVar.dateUserAccept.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), oneVar.estimatedDuration, oneVar.actualDuration)
        End If
    Next
```

The class is:

```
Public Class jsonPrjData
    Public Property TID() As Int16
    Public Property taskDescript() As String
    Public Property taskStatus() As Int16
    Public Property username() As String
    Public Property prjDescript() As String
    Public Property dateUserAccept() As Date
    Public Property estimatedDuration() As Int16
    Public Property actualDuration() As Int16
End Class
```

The line with `MsgBox(oneVar.TID.ToString)` doesn't return nothing, because of the error when desearializing null value. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: That is not valid json.  There are lots of extra quotes in there.  Do you have a better version/copy?

Comment: I have updated the JSON, this is how it is outputted by the php script.

Comment: Thats better - the old one even had the `:` marks quoted.  Does it really have stars around the null? or is that you?

Comment: That was the output from visual studio debugger.

Comment: What data type would `dateuseraccept` be when it is supplied?  Or what does `jsonPrjData` look like and where do you get the error

Comment: Can you share the full `ToString()` output of the exception, including message, exception type, traceback (in Json.NET) and inner exception?  You can get this information by catching the exception and writing it to the console, or via [copy exception to clipboard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276/).

Comment: @Plutonix I forgot about that class, Thank you. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I get `Error converting value {null} to type 'System.DateTime'. Path '[0].dateuseraccept', line 7, position 24.` with that class because what the msg says,  Use `DateTime?` for `dateuseraccept` and it works fine

Comment: @dbc this is the irony, I'm not getting any exception. That is the only "error" that I'm getting from the Output window when I run the program.

Comment: @Plutonix how did you got the error message? What do you mean by ``DateTime?``, I don't know how to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using that class, I get this error trying to deserialize:

> Error converting value {null} to type 'System.DateTime'. Path '[0].dateuseraccept'

So change that property in your class to:

```
Public Property dateuseraccept As DateTime?
' or
Public Property dateuseraccept As Nullable(Of DateTime)
```

Use whichever you prefer.  `DateTime?` / `Nullable(of DateTime)` seems to be needed here since in *that* json, `dateuseraccept` is null. A `Nullable` allows the variable to store null/Nothing **or** a valid datetime.

Since your error comes from `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` and the only code involving Json is your `DeserializeObject`, it is likely the same source.

Now, since that property can be a `DateTime` or null/Nothing, use `HasValue` to determine which is the case:

```
If item.dateuseraccept.HasValue Then
    Console.WriteLine(item.dateuseraccept)
Else
    Console.WriteLine("No Date")
End If
```

It may not be the only thing wrong, but it works fine for me with that.

[Nullable(Of T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx)